# Update mysql database fields with datepicker jquery ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datepicker

1. How can I **update mysql fields** without refreshing the page, from a list of results from the database.
2. Using **datepicker**
3. In a single .php page?

Example:

**order_report.php**

```
$query = $this->db->query("select order_id,
date_format(date_payed,'%d-%m-%Y') as date_payed,
from oc_order");

***code left out to save space***

foreach ($res as $orders) {
print $orders['order_id'];

<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" value="<?php echo $orders['date_payed']; ?>"/>
$query = $this->db->query("update oc_order SET date_payed='$datepicker' WHERE  order_id='$orders['order_id'];'");
}
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: This is a common misconception about server/client communication. PHP is on the server side. Javascript (datepicker) is on the client side. You clearly need a AJAX call to update you Database. But there's no Silver Bullet. Someone could write you the code so you could copy/paste and get it working, but what happens next time? Give google a go and check out how people work with php and AJAX. I guarantee it will be worthwhile. And if you get stuck, just come back to SO and make an specific question. Kind regards.

Comment: I´ve been trying to make this work for 3 days now. Biggest problem is that the datepicker won´t load when it is inside the foreach array.

Comment: Start by the basics of HTML and PHP form submission and how PHP is parsed. Your exemple of php code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: of course it won't load. you're outtputting the **SAME** dom `id=...` for every datepicker instance. dom IDs **MUST** be unique across the entire document.

Comment: So on the php side... <input type="text" id="datepicker<?php print $orders['order_id']; ?>" ...but what in the ajax script?

Comment: herezy, I only wrote the important parts in the php example which i need help with,

Comment: @ChristofferGustafsson Your biggest problem is far from being your datepicker. Your biggest problem is your entire php code: your <input> line is invalid syntax, your inputs have no name, your $dtpickerdate pops out of nowhere and is the same unset variable for every input, your update query is invalid mysql syntax and EXTREMELY insecure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming what you are asking is that you want the datepicker to update your MySQL table when you select on a date without having to refresh that page. The code you provided is a little confusing, but I put something together that may help.

I am guessing that the `input` field that's in your code is actually supposed to be the html where you are getting the value.

As for keeping it all on one single page... I don't think that will be possible. For best results, you will have to make a new `.php` page to accept the value of the datepicker, which is passed through the `$.ajax` call where it says `date`. If you did it on the same page, there's a possibility you may end up getting a swamp of unwanted html data returned to you via the `data` parameter in the `success` function, but it would most likely throw an error and get the `error` function callback.

In this example, I called the php page `process_date.php`.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" value="<?php echo $orders['date_payed']; ?>"/>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            onSelect: function () {
                var date = $("#datepicker").val();

                $.ajax({
                     type: "POST", //or GET. Whichever floats your boat.
                     url: "path/to/process_page.php",
                     data: { date: date },
                     success: function(data) {
                         alert(data);

                         //Write code here for you successful update (if you want to)
                     },
                     error: function() {
                         alert("Error.");
                     }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP (process_date.php)

```
<?php

    $date = $_POST['date'];  //if you used GET in your ajax, then use $_GET here instead


    $query = $this->db->query("select * from oc_order");

    ***code left out to save space***

    foreach ($products as $orders) {
        print $orders['order_id'];

        $query = $this->db->query("update oc_order SET date_payed='$date' WHERE  order_id='$orders['order_id'];'");

        echo "Success";
    }
?>
```

Note: Not saying you didn't, but don't forget to always sanitize your PHP data before sending it to the server in order to avoid being attacked via [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Even if you use parameterized queries, it is still a good idea.

Comment: Sorry my question is little confusing.
I have a table with all the orders from the shop, and in the last column I would want to select a date from the datepicker and update that row to the database